I'm trying to create an API in laravel but I'm having problems
I'm trying to create an API in Laravel, is there an api.php file in the routes folder in Laravel? or does it have to be done manually? because when I created it the file didn't appear
I tried looking for a solution on any website but couldn't find a way to fix it

In the routes/api.php folder the api routes are created and in the Providers/RouteServiceProvider folder it finds the default api prefix where it accesses an endpoint in the following way api/endpointexample

You need to go to routes/api.php and write the below given code in it.
Route::get('/demo', function () {
    return response('API Demonstration Success', 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});

You can either call the api route by using: http://localhost:8080/api/demo OR
http://localhost/projectname/api/demo

If you are using laravel 11, then you have to run this command to get api.php file, as in newer laravel release, they remove lots of pre-configured files. so if you want to create API's, then you will need api.php and to get it you will need to run php artisan install:api
then you can go to bootstrap/app.php and setup api route path
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
    then: function($router){
        Route::prefix('api/v1')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->name('api.v1')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
)


which version of laravel you are using?
if it is Laravel 11X, then you have to create routes/api.php file using the command
php artisan install:api

In Laravel 11 api.php and channels.php route files are no longer present by default.
for more details go to this link where I have already answered..
Creating api request on Laravel with Inertia
